# Why Windows Error Reporting did't stop?

Tags: networking

I want to disable the Windows Error Reporting but after disabling it's still running !! it's been started after I restarting the windows also it use a lot of network and I can't play any online game (because of my ping) . Is it possible that be a virus ?

[image]

Comment: Windows 10? How did you disable it?

Comment: yes windows 10 . In  services.msc I right clicked on windows error reporting and set disable in it properties but it can't disabled . I have to click on end task after windows turn on !!! how can i disable it for ever

Comment: From what I have read, other software installed by the pc manufacturer can trigger problem reporting regardless if the services setting. I doubt it is a virus.

Comment: @moab So what i have to do ? should i reinstall the windows ? it name is windows problem reporting but i disable windows error reporting !! it has different name

Comment: Different name but same thing, not sure what you should do. What Make and model of PC is it.

Comment: I use msi gf627rd . I check it on other pc but it's not appear anymore it just happened to my laptop

Comment: Right click on the Name entry in task manager, what choices are available in the context menu?

Comment: It's like other features has no difference